# I am getting following error while converting the CVS repository to SVN repository using cvs2svn

Tags: svn, cvs2svn, cvsnt

I am getting this error while while giving this command:

```
 cvs2svn --trunkonly --svnrepo /path/to/new/svn /path/to/existed/cvs/repo
```

The error i am getting is

```
   Error summary:
   ERROR: No RCS files found
   Are you absolutely certain you are pointing cvs2svn
   at a CVS repository?
```

I found that the my repository is CVSNT. so the above may not be working. Can anybody please give me some idea how to covert those repositories into SVN?

Answer (score 4):

As the error says: The path `/path/to/existed/cvs/repo` is probably wrong. Try again with the directory which contains `CVSROOT`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Acutally , i had a CVS repository in the remote computer. I copied those files in my local computer through scp. I have kept that CVS package somewhere in my local computer and giving path of that CVS package as CVS repository.Is this the proper way or I have to make any changes to it before giving it as path of CVS repository.

Comment: The CVS module is not enough; CVS keeps a lot of vital information in the directory CVSROOT so you must copy that as well.

Comment: It is true that CVS keeps important information in the CVSROOT directory, but cvs2svn doesn't use that info.  As far as cvs2svn is concerned, it is enough if there is an empty CVSROOT directory in the correct place (it is only used to find the main directory of the CVS repository).